# Help with objects in C++

Tags: c++, object

I have the code

```
class ogre
{
    public:
        int health;
        bool isalive;
        string name;
};

int fight()
{
    cout << "You're now fighting an ogre!" << endl;

    ogre ogre;
    player player;
    int ogredamage;
    int playerdamage;

    srand(time(NULL));

    ogre.name = "Fernando Fleshcarver";
    ogre.health = 100;
    ogre.isalive = true;

    player.health = 10000000;
    player.isalive = true;

    while(ogre.isalive = true)
    {
        ogredamage = rand() % 20;
        cout << ogre.name << " deals " << ogredamage << " damage to you!" << endl;
        player.health = player.health - ogredamage;
        cout << "You have " << player.health << " health left." << endl << endl;

        playerdamage = rand() % 20;
        cout << "You deal " << playerdamage << " damage to " << ogre.name << endl;
        ogre.health = ogre.health - playerdamage;
        cout << ogre.name << " has " << ogre.health << " health left." << endl;

        ogre.isalive = false;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

which compiles fine, however, when I try to set "ogre.isalive" (at the very bottom of the code) to false, nothing happens and the code keeps looping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't want to seed the random number generator every time `fight()` is called.  You just want to seed it once when your program starts.  If you call `fight()` twice within a short span of time, `time()` can return the same value and you'll get the same results twice.

Comment: Coolio, thanks for the heads up. (I'm not really familiar with "seeding" and how it works, I just got that code from some website and it happened to work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ogre.isalive = true
```

is an assignment! The while loop will always run because the result of the assigment is always true. You need `==` to test for equality. Better yet, just use

```
while(ogre.isalive)
```

Comment: Of course! I feel rather silly now. (You get the accepted answer because you answered first)

Comment: You probably don't want a semi-colon at the end of line!!

Comment: @grantz: Haha, true. It's the bad habit from programming in C-like syntax; you tend to end sentences with semi-colons;

Answer (score 6):

Your while condition is an assignment and then a check of ogre.isalive, which is of course true because you just assigned it:

```
while(ogre.isalive = true)
```

You want to check for equality:

```
while(ogre.isalive == true)
```

Or better yet, since the variable is already a boolean:

```
while(ogre.isalive)
```

Comment: I don't think it checks ogre.isalive. Doesn't it just check the result of the assignment (i.e. true)?

Comment: ogre.isalive is the result of the assignment.  It assigns a value of true to isalive and then checks.  Of course, that will always be true.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
                     vv
 while( ogre.isalive == true )
```

Or just

```
 while( ogre.isalive )
```

EDIT: Using

```
                     v
 while( ogre.isalive = true )
```

just assigns `true` on each step of the loop, this way your `while` will never stop.

Answer (score 2):

You have assignment (`ogre.isalive = true`) in the loop condition. It should be:

```
while(ogre.isalive)
...
```